# How to "name" a query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

In postgresql a query in the querylog gets something like this:

```
2009-02-05 00:12:27 CET LOG:  duration: 3781.634 ms  execute <unnamed>: SELECT QUERY ....
```

Is there a possibility to put something more usable into the "< unnamed >" placed like the url the query was requested from?

Are there any other possibilities to track the origin of a query in postgresql using jdbc from java?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer is "no"

The name can be set when preparing the statement, using the [PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-prepare.html) command, but that requires rewriting all your SQL. There is no option to simply add a name parameter to your JDBC methods.

The JDBC driver makes use of both named and unnamed prepared statements. It will give them a name when it wishes to reuse them, which it will deem appropriate if the same PreparedStatement object is executed 5 times (though that is configurable through setting the prepareThreshold).

Documentation is [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/server-prepare.html)

More info can also be found by searching the [PostgreSQL JDBC mailling list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/)